# Repeat rows in pandas and add a sequence column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which gets da Date from a calendar and extracts some feature out of the date.

```
def processDate(self,date):
    WEEKDAY_MAP = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[date], columns = ['DATE'])
    df['DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype(str)
    df['MONTH'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).month
    df['WEEKDAY'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).dayofweek
    df['WEEKDAY'] = df['WEEKDAY'].map(WEEKDAY_MAP)
    df['HOLIDAY'] = '0'
    set_holiday(df)
    df['INTERVALL'] = '1'
    df.append([df]*5,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

Console Log:

```
     DATE        MONTH  WEEKDAY HOLIDAY INTERVALL
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      1
```

What i need: duplicate the entry 48 times and increase the INTERVALL Value.

Outcome should be like this:

Console Log:

```
     DATE        MONTH  WEEKDAY HOLIDAY INTERVALL
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      1
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      2
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      3
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      4
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      5
     ...
     2017-09-13     9     3      0      48
```

I tried `df.append([df]*48,ignore_index=True)` but that didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat` and create a new dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(48, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
df['INTERVALL'] = df.index + 1
```

---

```
df.head(10)

         DATE MONTH WEEKDAY HOLIDAY  INTERVALL
0  2017-09-13     9       3       0          1
1  2017-09-13     9       3       0          2
2  2017-09-13     9       3       0          3
3  2017-09-13     9       3       0          4
4  2017-09-13     9       3       0          5

df.shape
(48, 5)
```

Comment: Don't think they want two  interval columns but that's minor.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Or rather a non-misspelling :)

Comment: :) Just follow the out put you have , so I got a 'misspelling' too...:)

Comment: @Wen LOL... 1 sec... need to undo some votes to +1 you

Answer (score 3):

Or  using `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df]*48,axis=0).reset_index()
df['INTERVAL'] = df.index+ 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own idea and then assign a range to the `INTERVALL` column

```
df= df.append([df]*47,ignore_index=True)
df["INTERVALL"] = range(1,49)
```

Note that you need to duplicate 47 times and then use the range from 1 till 48.